# How to set custom text for a button in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<Button android:id="@+id/AdultLeft1"
     android:layout_width="40dip" android:text="@layout/active"
     android:layout_marginTop="110dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/notselectedtabright_landscape"
     android:focusable="false"/>
```

and in `active.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <com.xxx.VerticalTextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textStyle="bold"android:textSize="12dip"
          android:text="Closed\nCases"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a custom `VerticalTextView`. I want to set this text to my Button in xml. How is that done?

Comment: Check `/res/values/strings.xml` file. And please explain in detail what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: actually i posted code here its not showing my code

Comment: this is my button code,on my button i want to display my custom textview   <Button android:id="@+id/KidRight1"                  android:layout_width="40dip"android:layout_height="110dip"android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/AdultLeft"android:text="@layout/closed1" android:background="@drawable/selectedtab_landscape"android:focusable="false"/> ,in closed.xml=<com.skynextech.firstdentalcare.VerticalTextViewandroid:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="@color/green"android:textStyle="bold"android:textSize="12dip" android:text="Closed\nCases"/>

Answer (score 0):

A string is a string in the resources and can be used by **ANY VIEW** this is a **BIG HINT**.

**Explanation**

```
android:text="@layout/active"
```

Ideally, this should be:

```
android:text="@string/myText"
```

Of course `myText` should be in your strings.xml

Comment: can you explain me with example am not getting

Comment: can you please give me example to set custom text for my button

Comment: If you can't figure it out from what I said, then you deserve to get it wrong. Learn your fundamentals.

Comment: if it is normal text i can give in string.xml,i want text in vertical so i added custom text.how to get that in strings.xml